# Can you make a compound predicate with "but" or not?

Tags: grammar, punctuation, predicate

I'm learning about commas, and some say you can't make compound predicate with "but". Others say you can. For example, the sentence: "We talked about not going to the meeting, but finally decided we should go."

Why does the above sentence need comma? We talked.. & we decided. Isn't it a compound predicate?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, of course you can. The comma is generally optional. The bracketing is _[We [talked about not going to the meeting], [but finally decided we should go]]_. The inner brackets surround a coordination of two predicate VPs, each with the common subject "we".

Comment: BillJ, thank you for the response! I needed that clarification. Is the comma optional because the sentence is short, or because the subject of the second pair of inner brackets is implicit?